# Postregsql Date Difference on basis on seconds

Tags: postgresql

How can I find date difference between two dates in terms of seconds in PostgreSQL?

There is no function for giving date difference in terms of seconds like in SQL-Server:

```
DATE_DIFF(second, '2011-12-30 09:55:56', '2011-12-30 08:54:55')
```

Please help me to have this in PostgreSQL too

Answer (score 56, accepted):

First, the dates need to be values of `timestamp` type (so append `::timestamp` if you're just specifying them as string literals).

If you subtract two timestamps, the result is of `interval` type, which describes a duration of time (in hours, minutes, seconds etc.) You can use `extract(epoch from interval_value)` to convert the interval into an absolute number of seconds.

So, putting that all together:

```
select extract(epoch from ('2011-12-30 09:55:56'::timestamp - '2011-12-30 08:54:55'::timestamp));
```

Remember that the `::timestamp` is only needed to convert the string literal to a timestamp: you don't need it if you're using the value of a timestamp column, for example.

Comment: I actually prefer ANSI literals: `timestamp '2011-12-30 09:55:56'` rather than casting a string value (mainly because they work in nearly all DBMS and I don't have to remember the DBMS specific syntax)

Comment: Thanks araqnid , I was trying to extract second after substracting timestamp , forgot about extracting epoch from substracted timestamp. Thanks 4 perfect answer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Good point, but one database that doesn't support that syntax is SQL Server, which I work with a lot. I always remember `cast(value as type)` as the standard syntax, which is a bit verbose.

Comment: But I think the cast syntax is influenced by language settings, right? So it depends on the system configuration what format the string literal should be in?

Comment: I was under the understanding that in postgresql, `cast(value as type)`, `type value` and `value::type` were all equivalent. Of course, the datestyle setting affects the interpretation, I didn't think the style of writing the cast was relevant.

Comment: Also, the `type value` syntax doesn't always fit: e.g. `date testfunc()` is a syntax error, whereas `testfunc()::date` and `cast(testfunc() as date)` are not

Comment: `date_part('epoch', date1::timestamp - date2::timestamp)`