# SQL difference between two rows with timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im working on with SQL on PostgreSQL
I have this table that describes images of cars with columns **camera**,**whn** and **reg**

Camera is int,whn is timestamp string(e.g. 2007-02-25 07:51:10) and reg is string

I am doing this assignment and im stuck on:

> "Print the register plate(reg) of cars which have been photographed twice by the same camera or different and the difference between the photos is a minute or less"

Does anybody know how i can express this difference between two different rows of the column whn that needs to be equal or less than 60 seconds?

Comment: **Never** store `timestamp` values as strings. That is a really, really bad idea

Comment: Have a look on converting your "timestamp-strings" to real ```timestamp```s and then use the ```interval``` type to add ```interval '60 seconds'```

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort your table by timestamp.
2. Use lag() from [windows function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-window.html) to get row below current row.
3. Use [extract()](https://learnsql.com/cookbook/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-postgresql/) to see different between two timestamp.

Comment: Why would you use extract() when - can do the trick? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html

Comment: Thanks @FrankHeikens , https://stackoverflow.com/a/13627033/8084062