# Find the difference in seconds between two dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

I have following query in oracle to get diff in seconds

```
SELECT TO_DATE('a', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') - TO_DATE(Q'b', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
FROM dual
```

i'm looking for equivalent query in postgres

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626887/postregsql-date-difference-on-basis-on-seconds

Comment: `TO_DATE('a', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')` will result in an error because `'a'` isn't a valid date string, same for `Q'b'`

Comment: In Oracle `date - date` returns the difference in (fractional) days, not in seconds

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (timestamp1- timestamp2)) FROM dual
```

Comment: `extract()` only works on `date`, `timestamp` or `interval` values. However, `date - date` returns an integer.

Comment: You can cast to timestamp easily with `somedate::timestamp`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Correct. Cast to  'timestamp' instead.